# calculate the numbers present in each row in a text file and plus them via php

Tags: php, text, count

I have a text file with multiple rows-

```
URL=> https://google.com/ ok=> 999 Result=> 200
URL=> https://instagram.com ok=> 999 Result=> 200
```

So I want to calculate all the numbers present after `ok=>` and before `Result=>`

Like there are 2 lines for example, then it should plus 999+999 = 1998 (this is the result I want to show in php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) along with the [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) as

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=(ok=>\s)).*?(?=(\sResult))/m','URL=> https://google.com/ ok=> 999 Result=> 200 URL=> https://instagram.com ok=> 999 Result=> 200',$res);
echo array_sum($res[0]);//1998
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/418004)

Comment: there is a text file and i want to show it in another php file.

Comment: This'll give you result and you can pass that result to your desired page within variable

Comment: can you please tell me how can i do that. i am little noob :( and i can't add php in the text file as it keeps updating .

Comment: How are you getting the string within your code just place that string value within your second parameter of `preg_match_all`

Comment: How to do that, like how to link the file $file = "link.txt";